# No puedo iniciar sesión en phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Acabo de instalarme phpmyadmin en mi mac y a la hora de poner los datos de mi sesión me sale el siguiente error:

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Socket operation on non-socket

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que debo hacer para poder solucionarlo?

Gracias

Comment: Puedes conectarte desde el cliente de linea de comandos de MySQL?

Comment: Si, desde la consola puedo entrar a MySQL sin problemas, crear tablas, borrar, rellenar, etc. El problema está cuando quiero entrar a phpmyadmin. Ahí me da el error.

Comment: Que va, no tengo antivirus. Por lo que he podido leer puede ser porque en mac no funciona bien si los enlaces simbólicos no están hechos, pero hago el enlace y nada.